# Multiple image upload to blobstore and GCS in one api call, slows the process and even timeout is happening in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, parallel-processing, blobstore

I am getting more then one image data from front and I am storing these images in GCS and also in blobstore.

This is happening in one api call, and image uploading is sequential, so it is taking too much time for this api call and timeout is happening.

Is there any way i can make it parallel? If i do it async the uploading process will be handled in background and I am not sure how many process can be handled in background and will it actually improve the performance.

Because this API call will be more often and each api call is having many images can any one help me to improve the process?

Comment: Why do you store images in GCS *and* Blobstore? Are you uploading images directly to GCS?

Comment: nop, original image is stored in GCS and size converted images and thumbnails are stored in blobstore.Lets not confuse in GCS and blobstore. I just wanted to ask weather I can do parallel processing even if I am using only blobstore.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers allow 6-10 simultaneous connections, so you can upload multiple files in parallel. Typically, however, there is little or no benefit of uploading more than 2-3 files in parallel as client bandwidth becomes the limiting factor. You should not expect to save a lot of time through parallel uploading.

When a user selects multiple files, the client initiates uploads of the first 2-3 files and listens to upload status events. When upload is successful, the client can start uploading the next file, if any. This allows you to split your single API call into one call per file.

Note that all App Engine calls have a size limit of 32MB and time limits depending on the scaling method. If you need to upload large files - or a large number of files, you need to upload them directly into the Cloud Store. If size limit is not an issue, you can use manual/basic scaling instances to avoid timeouts.

Also, you should separate image conversion/thumbnail creation into deferred tasks. This will allow your API call to return faster - before these tasks are executed.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information.If I use async and run uploading in background will it fail for more number of files?  And lets assume because of lots of uploading it may happen that differed task will fail.

Comment: The only reason for upload to fail is a lost connection. With individual uploads at least some files can succeed. If you upload all files at once, your client does not even know which files succeeded and which failed. You have to get this data from your server before telling a user so a user knows which files to retry.